# RViz camera view: other coordinate frame convention

Tags: ros, kinect, rviz, fovis-ros, fovis

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm currently doing some experiments with fovis_ros and a kinect . This works pretty well, but fovis uses an other type of coordinate frames where +X is to the right, +Y is down and +Z is forward. The thing is that none of the camera views in RViz are able to let the camera rotate around the Y axis instead of the X axis. This makes it kinda hard to get a nice view in RViz. It seems that RViz was only made for the coordinate frame conventions documented on this page: ros.org/wiki/geometry/CoordinateFrameConventions

Any of you guys encountered the same problem? Is there anyone with a solution for this problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55501/rviz-camera-view:-other-coordinate-frame-convention/) by [Robbiepr1](https://answers.ros.org/users/4154/robbiepr1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 143 on 2013-02-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Depending on the launch file you use for your kinect, it might be that there is already a `static_transform_publisher` running that publishes a tf between `camera_link` and `camera_rgb_optical_frame`. You can check that easily by running

```
rosrun tf tf_monitor
```

If you want, you can easily give this `camera_rgb_optical_frame` as base link frame id to fovis_ros:

```
rosrun fovis_ros stereo_odometer _base_link_frame_id:=/camera_rgb_optical_frame
```

fovis_ros will then publish movements through tf and odometry messages using /odom as fixed frame and /camera_rgb_optical_frame as the moving (child) frame.
If you set the fixed frame in rviz to /odom you should see the camera frames moving while moving the kinect.

---

Originally posted by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) with karma: 1924 on 2013-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Robbiepr1](https://answers.ros.org/users/4154/robbiepr1/) on 2013-02-18**:
Thanks! That did the trick for now. Although it would be nice if there was some kind of setting in RViz itself.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is the standard camera optical coordinate system.

The easiest solution I see to your problem is to publish a transform between the camera system and the camera's optical system, e.g. by using a `tf static_transform_publisher`.

Then select that system in rviz instead of the optical on that, you have now.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-02-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Switching the up axis might be a useful feature in RViz. You're welcome to open a feature request ticket on https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/issues

---

Originally posted by [dgossow](https://answers.ros.org/users/1564/dgossow/) with karma: 1444 on 2013-02-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) on 2013-02-18**:
+1! Especially for underwater robotics, where the standard coordinate system is NED (North East Down).

**Comment by [Robbiepr1](https://answers.ros.org/users/4154/robbiepr1/) on 2013-02-18**:
This would be a nice feature indeed. I will open a feature request on github

**Comment by [dgossow](https://answers.ros.org/users/1564/dgossow/) on 2013-02-19**:
After reviewing this I would say that this is a likely feature for a future RViz release.

**Comment by [dgossow](https://answers.ros.org/users/1564/dgossow/) on 2013-02-19**:
For further comments on the feature request please use the github tracker: https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/issues/597